# Microsoft Appfabric Configuration with mysql?

Tags: appfabric

I am totally stuck with Microsoft appfabric.I want to configure appfabric with mysql but there is no such help if anyone did please guide me to resolve this issue

Thanks in advance

Regards

Comment: Is there a specific problem? any error messages? please add some additional info (what you've done already).

Comment: It is not cofiguring with mysql please guide me how i customize with mysql

Answer (score 0):

You would have to write a library that implements the [ICustomProvider interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.applicationserver.caching.icustomprovider.aspx), persisting the data to MySQL, and [register it with AppFabric](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff383419%28v=azure.10%29.aspx) in order to use MySQL as the config provider.

It would be easier just to use an instance of SqlExpress..

Comment: There's an example implementation that uses Amazon s3 as the back-end [here](http://www.binpress.com/app/custom-configuration-provider-for-appfabric-caching/88)

Comment: I want appfabric to persist with mysql it configure with sqlserver by default but to configure with mysql i did all the step which are mentioned in msdn appfabric tutorial but i dont know either appfabric connected with mysql or not.I am beginner level at Workflows and Appfabric.My Question are the book and msdn while configuring mentioned that i write behavior at machine.config my question is what is this behaviour for and then add the behaviour at web.config. How workflow insert its persistence state to mysql table? where i write the insert query and how i call.

Comment: Which tutorial did you use?

Comment: Sorry for delay, I was busy in doing some other assignment,I am using Microsoft Custom Persistence Tutorial http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee473462(v=vs.110).aspx and also i downloaded the Cook book for appfabric.Its 2 weeks and i am totaly stuck what i do.Please guide me

Comment: Can you show the code for your implementatoion of [Custom Instance Store](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee829481%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which calls MySQL?